# Restoring .bkp files SP2010

Tags: 2010, content-database, restore, database-attach

How can I restore **.bkp** file and attach it in **SharePoint 2010**?

SQL Server throws this error when trying to restore like  a .bak file -

> media not supported

Comment: Ok - sorry. I misinterpreted the post. You have a .BKP file. Give me a second then...

Comment: I guess we would need some more info then. Are you sure the file you got was a database backup in the first place? The extension makes me think your file may have been generated using the Import/Export api, in which case you need to use the Import-SPWeb PowerShell command for the restore

Comment: Please provide more information. Your backup seems to be a SharePoint backup, so it cannot be restored on SQL-Server. From which SharePoint-Version was the backup taken (2010 or older?)